# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis

I have a .Net Core 2.2 project (web API) that uses as a dependency a .Net Framework 4.7.2 (classic) library.

Project structure:

- BLL (classic library, it uses **Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule** nuget package)
- Web.API.(Net Core app)

I build the .Net Core app using the below command:

```
dotnet.exe publish -o "${publishWorkspace}\website_web_api" /property:Configuration=Debug
```

When I deploy the project on AWS Beanstalk (IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2016/2.7.2) I get this error when I try to access the API URL:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

this is the problematic NuGet package reference in the "BLL" .Net Framework library csproj:

```
...
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.1.1.0\lib\Net462\Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
...
```

I tried adding the `bindingRedirect` to the `BLL.dll.config` and restarting IIS server but that did not help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" /></startup></configuration>
```

Installed SDKs on the AWS Beanstalk instance:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.818 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.413 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]        
5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.net) it should support those .Net versions:

- .NET 5.0.11, supports **5.0.11, 3.1.20, 2.1.30**
- .NET Framework 4.8, supports **4.x, 2.0, 1.x**

**UPDATE**

I tried to run the deployed API app using the terminal by running `dotnet .\Web.API.dll environment=Development`

That returned this error:

```
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.30 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      3.1.19 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      5.0.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

So I installed the 2.2 Runtime (via the hosting bundle from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.2/runtime?utm_source=getdotnetcore&utm_medium=referral)) and then retried the above command and this time it ran fine and started listening for requests.

However, when I tried to use the URL that I set up for the API project via the IIS server, I get the same "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule" error.

I tried restarting the IIS Server as well, no luck

**UPDATE 2**

After enabling "Fusion!EnableLog" logging (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)). I got some more info regarding the assembly load problem:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/BackendAPI/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\BackendAPI\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\BackendAPI\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/api/27eecc96/2976b187/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/api/27eecc96/2976b187/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/BackendAPI/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/BackendAPI/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/api/27eecc96/2976b187/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/api/27eecc96/2976b187/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/BackendAPI/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/BackendAPI/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule.EXE.
```

I suspect the issue is that there is no `bin` folder in the location where the API project is deployed but not sure why that is the case

Comment: 1. .NET Core 2.2 is end of life. 2. Never consume a .NET Framework assembly in a .NET Core project (exceptions are rare and only a guru knows what he/she is doing). So in your case, get rid of that dependency is your only option, because clearly it was only designed for the old ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do plan to migrate that .Net Framework library to .Net Core 3.1 but I am hoping to figure out a way to make it work for the time being. Please see the "UPDATE 2" section I just added

Comment: You won't find a way when that's a dead end.

Comment: The bit that I do not understand (see Update 1) is that when I run the app using the `dotnet wepapi.dll` command the app starts and listens for requests. I do not get the above file not found exception

Comment: Set the "Enable 32-bit applications" to "true" in advanced settings of iis application pool and try again.

Comment: Thanks @samwu I tried that already, it is set to `True` currently but I still get the error

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609484/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-39microsoftaspnets-1.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609484/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-39microsoftaspnets-1.html).